# "Code in Interfaces" Kotlin, how do they avoid the "deadly diamond of death"?

Tags: interface, kotlin, diamond-problem

I was reading [this](https://antonioleiva.com/interfaces-kotlin/#comment-8057) article and it says that you can write code in Kotlin interfaces. Java did not allow writing code in interface to avoid diamond problem as of this [answer](https://www.quora.com/How-does-using-an-interface-in-Java-solve-the-diamond-problem/answer/Usman-Saleem?srid=hSxyQ). If Kotlin allows code in interface and multiple interfaces can be implemented in a class, doesn't this create the "Diamond Problem" all over again?

Comment: `Java did not allow writing code in interface` It does: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html

Comment: yeah I said it did not, now it does (after Java 8). please read the article i linked

Comment: Did you try to just create an example to see what happens?

Comment: neither java nor kotlin support multiple inheritance. do you understand what "diamond problem" refers to really?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski He refers to a class that implements multiple interfaces even though the interfaces have code in them.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I do understand Diamond problem, once again please read the article I linked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scenario 1

Two interfaces have methods with same signature and both don't have implementation in interface then it need to implement a method single method with same signature.

Example

```
interface InterfaceA {
    fun sum(a: Int, b: Int)
}

interface InterfaceB {
    fun sum(x: Int, y: Int)
}

class TestClass : InterfaceA, InterfaceB {
    override fun sum(x: Int, y: Int) {
       return a+b
   }
}
```

Scenario 2

Two interfaces have methods with same signature and different return type will be an error in this case

Example

```
interface InterfaceA {
    fun sum(a: Int, b: Int):Int = a+b
}

interface InterfaceB {
    fun sum(x: Int, y: Int)
}

class TestClass : InterfaceA, InterfaceB {
    override fun sum(x: Int, y: Int) {
       return a+b
   }
}
```

In this case compiler show error because both method must have same return type

The diamond problem is associated with multiple inheritance of classes that is not allowed in Kotlin as well as Java though you can create a scenario of diamond shape by implementing an interface with two interfaces then in kotlin you need to override all of methods otherwise it is a compile time error and this avoid diamond shape problem.

Example

```
interface InterfaceA {
    fun sum(a: Int, b: Int): Int {
        print("InterFaceA");
        return a + b
    }
}

interface InterfaceB:InterfaceA {
    override fun sum(a: Int, b: Int): Int {
        print("InterFaceB");
        return a + b
    }
}

interface InterfaceC:InterfaceA {
    override fun sum(a: Int, b: Int): Int {
        print("InterFaceC");
        return a + b
    }
}

interface InterfaceD : InterfaceB, InterfaceC {
    override fun sum(a: Int, b: Int): Int {
        print("InterFaceD");
        return a + b
    }
}
```

override is necessary otherwise compiler will show an error and won't proceed further.